# Passing custom class object as a value into STL map

Tags: c++, object, vector, stl, reference

I want to pass object of a custom class as a value into STL map. How do I do that..?

here is a code:

```
class demo
{

int a, b,c,d,e;

}

// here is how declare my map:

map<int, demo*> my_map;
```

This is how, I am using it into function:

```
demo *ptr = NULL;
ptr = new demo;
```

Here is how I am inserting into map

```
my_map.insert(make_pair(int, ptr);

// Delete current instance

delete ptr;
```

Is this a correct way..?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, no. If you want to store your `demo` objects in a `map`, you should use `map<int, demo>`. Leave the resource management to `std::map`. Also, by using `delete ptr` you destroy the just created object, and `my_map[index]` will be an invalid pointer.

Just use `my_map.insert(make_pair(myIndex, myDemoObject));`.

Also note that using `my_map[myIndex]` will create the object with the given index if it doesn't exist, so you can just do the following:

```
std::map<int, demo> my_map;
my_map[1].a = 42;
my_map[2].b = 1337;
my_map[3].c = 314159;
my_map[4].d = 23;
```

Comment: Actually I want to create 4 new instances of demo class and assign values of it members (i.e. a,b,c,d,e) to 4 different  "Key". That's why I call delete ptr so that new instance of demo class is created.

Comment: Also, I intentionally left out some piece of code after insert function.. I only pasted relevant portion of the code.

Comment: Also, I intentionally left out some piece of code after insert function.. I only pasted relevant portion of the code.

Comment: @user2812535: Edited my answer. If you don't understand _why_ this works, you most-likely don't understand _references_ yet. If this is the case, you should have a look at them. Either way, try to avoid `new`. If you want to insert a new demo, just create it beforehand: `demo myDemo; my_map.insert(make_pair(..., myDemo));`

Comment: Did you notice my_map[1] causes 'demo' class destructor to be invoked twice? (This could be a potential problem in case if we are deleting pointers in destructor)